# redirect customer on custom page from Indexcontroller

Tags: magento, redirect, custom-pages

I want to redirect customer even if he is not logged in, on my custom page where customer need to add quote and details of product. He will redirect on this page when he click on ‘Add to Compare’ link from product view page and after submitting form he will stay over there as it is with successful message.

Please note that,this thing I have to done from preDispatch function of Index Controller.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please describe clearly with screenshots if possible so other can help.

Comment: I am explaining this with an example. When Customer click on "Add to Wishlist" that time customer will redirect to a custom page.Now as I debug,first function which is called,named 'preDispatch'. So from here I need to edit code in  a way that my requirement is satisfied (customer, even he is not logged in, will redirect to my custom phtml page).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code in config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <controller_action_before>
                    <class>dispatcher/observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionPreDispatch</method>
                </controller_action_before>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Add code in model/observer.php file

```
public function controllerActionPreDispatch($observer)
{
    //we compare action name to see if that's action for which we want to add our own event
    if($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'yourmodule Action Name') 
    {
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("customer/account"));
    }
}
```